# create custom shadow in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a container with specific kind of inner shadow.
but I don't have any idea that how to build it.

as you can see there is a light black shadow on upper left corner and a white shadow on the bottom right corner

[image: Like This One]

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a `BoxDecoration` in your `Container` and in a `BoxDecoration` you can use multiple `BoxShadow`s example:

```
BoxDecoration(
  color: //whatever color you want
  boxShadow:[
    BoxShadow(
      color: //shadow color
      offset: //shadow offset
      spreadRadius: //shadow spread radius. 
      //Use negative value above for the inner shadow effect
      blurRadius: //shadow blur radius
    ),
    BoxShadow(
    //same attributes but change them as you wish
    ),
  ]
)
```

check out flutter docs: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxShadow/BoxShadow.html

Here is an example code:

```
Container(
  height: 100,
  width: 100,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
  boxShadow: [
    BoxShadow(
      color: Colors.black12,
    ),
    BoxShadow(
      color: Colors.white,
      spreadRadius: -0.1,
      blurRadius: 2,
      offset: Offset(3, 3),
    ),
  ]),
),
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: this is a completely wrong answer , because the shadow will overFlow the box. please look carefully at the picture.

Comment: look at the new edit. My bad missed that. And thanks to [Omer Celik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7043190/omer-celik) for the edit.

Comment: I've added an example code & image that shows the end result. @mohammad you can mess with the values to get exactly what you want.